# call "flutter pub dev" using C# with Process class

Tags: c#, flutter

I am working on a sample CLI tool which clones a repo and calls “Flutter pub dev” programmatically using C# everything is working fine except the last “Flutter pub dev”. Command below code is returning “an error occurred trying to start process 'flutter' with working directory”. I can see the working directory getting created properly, all other command is working except for the flutter. Any ideas how to fix it ?

```
StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    FileName = "flutter",
    Arguments = "-- version",
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    UseShellExecute = false,
    CreateNoWindow = true,
    RedirectStandardError = true,
}
```

This issue is only happening in the C# code, when I CD into the cloned repo and run the flutter command from terminal it is working fine.

I am using macOS Monterey and VS for Mac 17.5.3.